# Overriding stylesheets

Tags: html, css

I have a link, where I want to change the color of the text away from the color that I set for hyperlinks. My code is:

```
<span class="button"><%= link_to "Create new scenario", :action => "create" %></span>
```

And my CSS is:

```
a:link { 
  color:rgb(50%, 15%, 5%);
  text-decoration:none; 
} 


.button {
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
  background-color:rgb(93%, 93%, 93%);
  border:1px solid black;
  color:black !important;
  line-height:1.9;
  margin:0 3px 3px 0;
  padding:4px 8px 4px 3px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

For some reason the hyperlink text is still brown, rgb(50%, 15%, 5%).

Answer (score 3):

You could make a css style .button a:link {color: black;}

Comment: ITYM: .button a:link {color:#000}

Comment: Thank you! I should've remembered that Google is, indeed, my friend... =]

Answer (score 3):

Change your css to use the .button class and anchors with a parent css class of .button. as shown below:

```
.button,.button a:link {
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
  background-color:rgb(93%, 93%, 93%);
  border:1px solid black;
  color:black !important;
  line-height:1.9;
  margin:0 3px 3px 0;
  padding:4px 8px 4px 3px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

**EDIT:** Keep in mind that this causes the border to repeat and makes the hyperlink show up without an underline because of text-decoration:none. The best practice in this case is to have a separate css declarations.

```
.button {....}
.button a:link {.....}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because of the specificity; the `span` (.button) is less specific to the link than the `a:link` so the `a:link` styles are being applied (correctly according to the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

If you want to override the `a:link` styles for this one button (or...well, any other in the same way) add the class to the `<a>` tag rather than its parent element.

Though you might get away with:

```
.button > a:link {/* styles */}
```

Which should become specific since this one `<a>` is the descendant of the the span of class `.button`.

#### Edit:

It's worth pointing out that the '`>`' selector applies only to immediate descendants, so an `a` inside an element of class `.button` would be affected, however an `a` inside a div in turn inside an element of class `.button` would not be affected.

Also this selector is not supported by IE (certainly below version 7, and I don't know about version 7 -or, indeed, version 8). It might be okay to use, instead, the '`*`' operator:

```
.button * a:link {/* styles */}
```

bearing in mind that while this is supported -I think- in IE after version 5.x at least, it's a little broad in that it will target all `a`s within an element of class `.button`, regardless of any interim elements, and will still likely be less-specific than any rule applied to `a:link`s.

Comment: I think IE doesn't support child selectors.

Comment: Indeed, and this was pointed out in the 'wrong' place, since the person pointing it out originally (billyswong) is as yet unable to comment on others' answers.

Answer (score 0):

"`! important`" is not for forcing child's style. It's for the user to override styles assigned by webpage author. It has no use in your case.

The proper way to do it is:

```
.button {
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
  background-color:rgb(93%, 93%, 93%);
  border:1px solid black;
  color:black;
  line-height:1.9;
  margin:0 3px 3px 0;
  padding:4px 8px 4px 3px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.button a {
  color:black;
}
```

Remarks:

1. "`.button > a`" is a good idea but it won't work in IE6. Therefore one should use "`.button a`" here to be safe.
2. Putting "`.button`" and "`.button a`" together in one set of style will make the button border repeat itself.

Comment: Thank you, that's why I first advocated using an explicit class (or id if it's a one-off) on the <a> element. It just makes more sense to me.

Comment: Well, it seems that the questioner is using PHP or something like that and somehow could not or hard to add explicit class onto the auto-gen'ed link.

And beware that "`>`" is not for descendants in general. It is specific to immediate children.

(I wish I have reputation high enough to comment on others' comments...)

Comment: While I didn't define the 'immediate-descendant' only relationship, I did appreciate that it was so. I'll amend my post slightly to reflect that more clearly. Thanks for the feedback